# Get notification on cgroup process change?

Tags: linux, inotify, cgroups

Basically, inotify which normally serves to notify on filesystem changes doesn't work within the cgroup virtual filesystem.

Essentially I want a way to get a notification similar to inotify when a process in a cgroup either is dies or forks. I tried attaching inotify to the `tasks` virtual file inside the cgroup filesystem but that does nothing when a process forks on its own, only when a usespace tool actually manually writes to it to influence the cgroup.

Answer (score 5):

`inotify` does not work on such virtual file system, be it `cgroup`, `proc` or `sys`.

Note: I tried this too, it would have been very handy in some situations, but nope. :-)

This is because the files and directories *do not actually exist* per see (for example they take 0 disk space), they are *produced for you on the fly by the kernel as you visit them*.

So the alternative would be to actively visit the files and dir in a busy loop periodically, which is so ugly that it is not a real alternative in most cases.

And this is why programs such as `top`, `htop` and such consume so much CPU. They do actually and actively browse the `proc` virtual file system rather than `inotify` or `select` or stuff like that in an eventing manner.

EDIT:

But there are some things that could help you though:

1/ For recent kernels (cgroups have been re-designed):

Look at:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt

I quote:

> 2-3. [Un]populated Notification
>
> Each non-root cgroup has a "cgroup.events" file which contains
>   "populated" field indicating whether the cgroup's sub-hierarchy has
>   live processes in it.  Its value is 0 if there is no live process in
>   the cgroup and its descendants; otherwise, 1.  poll and [id]notify
>   events are triggered when the value changes. [...]

1/ For older kernels:

You may want to have a look at `notify_on_release` and `release_agent`. Have a look at:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt

> - notify_on_release flag: run the release agent on exit?
> - release_agent: the path to use for release notifications (this file    exists in the top cgroup only)

And the sections "1.4 What does notify_on_release do ?" and "1.5 What does clone_children do ?"

Comment: NB: It is also possible to get notifications if you have registered an appropriate file descriptor with eventfd. In cgroups2 you can also use inotify (see https://archive.fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/cgroupv2/attachments/slides/1792/export/events/attachments/cgroupv2/slides/1792/cgroupv2_cdown_fosdem.pdf )